# Why is org.ietf, org.omg, org.w3c, and org.xml part of the POJOs?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Hi all I was wondering how did the packages `org.ietf`, `org.omg`, `org.w3c`, and `org.xml` made it into the ["official" Java classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html) ?

For example, it makes sense that the default JDK wouldn't have all the classes from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/),

By the same philosophy, shouldn't these `org.w3c`, `org.omg` packages be outside of the default JDK classes (i.e. not included within the JDK installation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all generally code representing standards, IETF, OMG, and W3C are all standards organizations. The code that you are referring to was created with these package names and was/is very widely used so it made sense to put it into the JDK with their original names. An exception to the standards name is the org.xml package. That has SAX which is an early Java/XML open source implementation of streaming XML event handling that became very popular. It's also code that is at the right level (a fairly low level) in the programming hierarchy so that it will be generally needed universally. Some of it is code that other parts of the Java runtime environment depend on.

Code in open source projects like Apache Commons is either not a standard or not required by other parts of the Java runtime, so there is no strong reason to include it.

Note in other cases, Sun/Oracle has added code external to the JDK to implement core features ([Doug Lea's concurrency stuff](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html) comes to mind), but these packages were renamed into `java` packages.

Comment: but xml isn't a "standards organization" is it?

Comment: No, it's not, and you will note I did not include it in my list of standards organizations. The org.xml code is SAX which is an early Java open source project providing that interface. I will revise my answer to mention this.